# Expanding variables inside ConvertFrom-Json reponses

Tags: json, powershell

I've built a series of JSON files that will be referenced by various modules and scripts. In the JSON, I make references to variables that will already exist in the PowerShell instance (and scope) that the script/module is in.
The problem is that the variables referenced in the `ConvertFrom-Json` appear to imported a literal, so the variables aren't expanding once they are in the session.

When you glance at `test.ps1` below, you'll see what I've tried to do, and what my goal is (I hope). If not, please ask me to explain. Sometimes I'm not the best at conveying what I'm after!

`test.ps1`:

```bsh
# The following Invoke-WebRequest just pulls in the JSON in this Gist
$JSON = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mpearon/a8614d73793c582760a6e2b9668d4f62/raw/2000ded35b6c8f9dd790f36a3169810acd5e3bdf/test.json' |
        ConvertFrom-Json
$ConnectionParams = @{
  ComputerName = $JSON.Server.connectionParameters.ComputerName
  ErrorAction  = $JSON.Server.connectionParameters.ErrorAction
  Credential   = $JSON.Server.connectionParameters.Credential
}
Enter-PSSession @ConnectionParams
```

`test.json`:

```json
{
  "Server" : {
    "connectionType" : "PSSession",
    "connectionSubType" : "ServerType",
    "securityLevel" : "Level1",
    "connectionParameters" : {
      "ComputerName" : "ServerNameHere",
      "ErrorAction" : "Stop",
      "Credential" : "$Creds"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not put relevant parts of your question on external sites, and particularly not on Gist. Your question will become useless as soon as the gist disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple values you could force variable epxansion like this:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ... | Select-Object -Expand Content
$json = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($response) |
        ConvertFrom-Json
```

However, that usually won't work with complex data types like `PSCredential` objects. Those would be inserted as their string representation.

If you know which option exactly you need expanded you could use `Invoke-Expression`:

```
$json = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ... |
        Select-Object -Expand Content |
        ConvertFrom-Json
$json.Server.connectionParameters.Credential = Invoke-Expression $json.Server.connectionParameters.Credential
```

Other than that I don't think PowerShell has something built-in that would do what you want. Besides, I fail to see where loading complex data structures from the network then filling (arbitrary?) parts of them with local variables would be useful.

Comment: The Invoke-WebRequest is not how I will be handling it in Production - just for the benefit of this audience.

It will be stored on a network location and used for multiple Modules throughout the company - sort of a data backbone.

Different connection types (ie: PSSessions to File/Share servers vs. Exchange Endpoints) will require different credentials - but the credentials will be defined in the session before the JSON is referenced - which is why I need the local expansion.

The second option you listed there will work for my purposes.
Thank you very much!